# Possibilities and best practises regarding deployment of GPO for the user right "Log on as a service"

Tags: security, group-policy, service

**Background**

I have a case where a developer computer is in a environment where the IT department have set up a forced group policy for the user rights assignment policy "Log on as a service". The policy is set to be forced and not editable and therefore replaces the local settings totally.

As this is a development computer with SQL Server Developer Edition installed and a running IIS, this user right is used by both the default SQL Server accounts as well as the virtual accounts for the applications pools (which av dynamically added/removed to/from this user right when an application pool is added or removed). Without the SQL Server service account added to this user right, the SQL Server will not even start.

Personally I find it strange to have a forced GPO that prohibits default behaviour for a local user right. The IT department have added a bunch of admin service groups as well as a bunch of special user groups that seems to have been added as a workaround for other developer departments in the organization. Purely security wise I also question why other development departments should get the access "Log on as a service" on my computer when they really just want that access to their local computers.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to deploy a GPO in way so it only adds the server settings to the local settings instead of replaces them?
2. Is is possible to deploy a GPO and still let it be editable by the local user?
3. Is possible to deploy the GPO in any other way so it doesn't affect the local settings?
4. Would it work with a workaround where a user group is added to the server GPO and where the local admin on the developer machine has access to administrate and add local service accounts to this group?
5. Would the method in no 4 work with the virtual accounts from the Application Pool or do they need to have direct access to the user right instead of implicitly through a user group?
6. What is best practices regarding GPO's for the user right "Log on as a service"? Spontaniously it seems strange to handle the user right the way it is done by this IT department.

**Environment**

Developer Machine:
Windows 8.1 Enterprise Eng

AD Server:
domainControllerFunctionality: 5 = ( WIN2012 ); 
domainFunctionality: 4 = ( WIN2008R2 ); 
forestFunctionality: 4 = ( WIN2008R2 );

Don't know if this indicates a Win2008R2 or Win2012-server.

Would really appreciate both detailed information about what's possible when it comes to GPO deployment as well as best practices and creative solutions of the specific problem!

Comment: You can use the GPO Preferences node instead of the Policies node to set GPOs which may be customised at the target computer. If the preference is set to replace, any customisations will be lost at next update however (and some other info you can get from the gpmc built in help file).

Answer (score 1):

Every GPO is "forced".

The answer to 1 to 3 is a resounding NO.

In this case, I'd ask them to create users for the SQL Server services. Those users should be added to the the group allowed to run as a service,  then  configure the local SQL machine to run using those credentials.

Microsoft has a Threats and Countermeasures guide. Look it up. I'll paste it here. I'm on mobile so forgive me for not formatting it properly.

> Log  on as a  service
>
> This policy  setting  determines  which  service  accounts  can  register  a process  as  a  service. In Windows  Server  2008  R2  and  Windows  7,  only  the  Network  Service  account  has  this right  by default. Any  service  that  runs under  a separate  user  account  must  be  assigned this user right.
>
> Possible  values:  User-defined list  of accounts / Not  Defined Vulnerability
>
> Vulnerability: Log  on  as a service  allows  accounts  to  start  network services  or services  that  run  continuously on  a  computer,  even  when  no  one  is logged  on  to  the  console. The  risk  is  reduced  by  the  fact that only  users with administrative  privileges  can  install  and  configure  services. An  attacker  who has already  attained  that  level  of access  could  configure  the  service  to  run  with  the  Local System account.
>
> Countermeasure: By  definition, the  Network  Service  account  has  the  Log  on  as a  service  user  right.  This right  is not  granted through  the Group  Policy  setting. You  should  minimize  the  number  of other accounts  that  are  granted this user right.
>
> Potential  impact:  On most  computers,  restricting  the  Log  on  as a service  user  right  to  the  Local System,  Local Service, and  Network Service  built-in  accounts  is  the  default configuration,  and  there  is no negative  impact.  However,  if you  have  installed  optional components  such  as  ASP.NET  or IIS,  you may need  to  assign  the  Log  on  as a service  user right  to  additional accounts  that  are required  by those  components. IIS  requires that  this user right  be  explicitly  granted  to  the ASPNET  user account.